# Data Trigger conditions check in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, setter, datatrigger

If any possible to give condition on DataTrigger?

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MessageBoxImage}" Value="{x:Static MessageBoxImage.Error}">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Images/Error48.png"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MessageBoxImage}" Value="{x:Static MessageBoxImage.Hand}">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Images/Error48.png"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MessageBoxImage}" Value="{x:Static MessageBoxImage.Stop}">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Images/Error48.png"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

So, this is my Xaml code, in that Error,Hand,Stop all are setting same image

My question is any possible to give OR condition for these three values? (or one line statement)

Thanks,

Comment: With the simple DataTrigger is meant to check for a single values. if Possible you could use the Multi-DataTrigger to check the multiple conditions.

Comment: @Vikram - You can have `IValueConverter` which will return true based on value passed to it (`Error, Hand and Stop`).

Comment: @Sankarann : If possible put it in answer, Thanks

Comment: @RohitVats : Oh yeah, in code behind we will create property for this and set true and checks here, any option in xaml?

Comment: No,there is not any possible way in XAML. Also `MultiDataTirgger` is `AND` operation and not `OR` operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MultiDataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for AND condition. As for OR condition you can use converter.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <someNs:ORConverter x:Key = "ORConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

....

<DataTrigger Value="True">
   <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <Binding Path="MessageBoxImage" Converter="{StaticResource ORConverter}">
            <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                <x:Array Type="MessageBoxImage">
                     <x:Static MemberType="MessageBoxImage" Member="Error" />
                     <x:Static MemberType="MessageBoxImage" Member="Information" />
                     <x:Static MemberType="MessageBoxImage" Member="Question" />
                </x:Array>
            </Binding.ConverterParameter>
        </Binding>
   </DataTrigger.Binding>

   <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Images/Error48.png"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

And the converter's code:

```
public class ORConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
           object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
         var list = parameter as IList;
         if (list == null)
             return false;

         foreach (var o in list)
         {
             if (Equals(o, value))
                return true;
         }

         return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
           object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot convert back");
    }
}
```

Comment: So only way to do is using IValueConverter to backend code, not possible to use OR in XAML, Now I understand Thanks to RohitVats and Tony

Answer (score 1):

With the simple DataTrigger is meant to check for a single values. if Possible you could use the Multi-DataTrigger to check the multiple conditions.

Comment: `MultiDataTrigger` is for `And` operation. `OR` operation cannot be achieved via MultiDataTrigger.